# Trouble Installing Selenium RC Java Client Driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm trying to set up Selenium RC with Eclipse, but when I download the .zip from the Selenium HQ website it comes with several files included. Which is the Java Client Driver that I need to include in my project?

Comment: Did you attempt to read any of the documentation on the seleniumHQ page?  Its literally right inside of the documentation section.  http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client driver is `selenium-java-2.0b3.jar` if you are using the one that is on the SeleniumHQ site. I'd recommend downloading the release candidate [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list), which is a more recent version. (It probably hasn't made it to the main site yet because it was uploaded only 4 hours ago.)